# I won't use try-catch statement in finally blcok. (java)

Tags: java, stream, garbage-collection, connection, try-catch-finally

Here is some java code.

```
public class SomeClass {
private Connection connection;

public SomeClass(Connection c) {
    connection = c;
}
public void someWork(){
    Connection c;
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // some exception code
    } finally {
        if (conn != null){
            try {c.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

}

but I don't like code

```
if (conn != null){
        try {c.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

so I think code

```
...catch (Exception e) {
        // some exception code
    } finally {
        c = null;
    }
```

but i see 'Stream object not Garbage Collected.'

I won't use try-catch statement in finally block.
Please give me another way.

Comment: Why won't you? Seriously, I can't see a reason for arbitrarily forbidding a language construct nested inside another.

Comment: More importantly, why would you ignore the exception?  Every time I see a try catch block that just swallows an exception I feel like crying.  That's just making somebody's life hard when debugging later.

Answer (score 6):

Just create a static utility method:

```
private static void closeQuietly(final Connection conn)
{
    if (conn == null)
        return;
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (WhateverException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Then

```
conn = whatever(); // create it there, not in the try block
try {
    // work
} catch (WhateverException e) {
    // whatever
} finally {
    closeQuietly(conn);
}
```

But eventually, you *will* use a try/catch in the finally block anyway.

Note that catching `Exception` is a **bad idea**. Catch exceptions which are specifically raised by `conn.close()` instead. Catching `Exception` means you also catch all `RuntimeException`s; and that is a Bad Thing(tm).

If you use Guava, you can also use [`Closeables.closeQuietly()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.Closeable%29), which does pretty much the same thing as the code above. You may also have a look at [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html), which is very interesting.

Finally (pun intended): if you use Java 7, use a try-with-resources statement instead (see [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)):

```
try (
    conn = whatever();
) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for information. i should write about my environment. i use jdk 6. but i really don't find any reasons why catching exception for every case. i usually use `Exception e` and `e.printStackTrace()` then it works like this `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:138)` really you think its a Bad way? i think i catch error what is and where is it.

Comment: What I say is that if you catch `Exception`, you also catch exceptions which have nothing to do with your workflow

Answer (score 1):

**Another work around for this would be to remove the catch all together inside the method:**

```
public void someWork() throws SQLException{
    Connection c;
    try {
        // do something
    } finally {
        if (conn != null){
            c.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you do your error checking outside the method in the main method where you invoked `someWork` method or you wrap it in another method where you call the `someWork()`:

```
 public void callSomeWork(){
    try{
     someWork();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
    //handle SQL error here
    }
 }
```

This way error thrown in try or finally will declared in one SQLException.

Answer (score 1):

You might not like that code, but in this situation it is necessary.  (Though you can wrap the code in a method like @fge's `closeQuietly` method.)

**But there is a more fundamental problem.**  Changing `someWork` to close the connection in a `finally` block is *not sufficient* to prevent a leak ... in this situation!!

Why?

Consider this:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(createConnection());
// do some stuff
sc.someWork();
```

Q1: What happens if an exception is thrown in the "do some stuff" code?

Q2: What happens if an exception is thrown while creating / constructing the `SomeClass`?   (Note: this is possible even with the simplest of constructors.  For example, an OOME could be thrown by the `new` operation ...)

Answer: the Connection object is leaked ... in both bases!

---

The fix is to allocate the resource (e.g. the Connection object) within, or immediately before the try / catch / finally; e.g.

```
Connection c = createConnection();
try {
    // do something
} catch (SomeException e) {
    // some exception code
} finally {
    if (c != null){
        try {c.close();} catch (SomeException e) {}
    }
}
```

In Java 7 you can also write it like this:

```
try (Connection c = createConnection()) {
    // do something
} catch (SomeException e) {
    // some exception code
}
```

provided that `Connection` implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.  The Java 7 version is "syntactic sugar" for a more complicated implementation that takes care of checking for `null`, calling `close()` and dealing with any resulting exceptions intelligently.  (The JLS gives the details of what "try with resource" actually does.)

---

For the record:

- The issue is not garbage collection / collecting.  The issue is that the `Connection` object needs to be *closed*.
- Assigning `null` won't cause an object to be closed.  It won't even cause it to be garbage collected.  At best, it can make the object *eligible* for garbage collection ... in some future GC run.
- Catching `Exception` is a really bad idea.  Read this: [Need authoritative source for why you shouldn't throw or catch java.lang.Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578557/need-authoritative-source-for-why-you-shouldnt-throw-or-catch-java-lang-excepti)

Comment: @user2503993 - That is unfortunate.  But if you are going to use an out-of-date version of the language, you have to put up with its limitations.  Learn to "like it".

Comment: @user2503993 - Also note (AND TELL YOUR BOSS / CLIENTS) that Java 6 has been EOLd.  No more security updates ... unless he / they take out an Oracle Java support contract.  http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_6.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may be leaving a zombie connection if not closed and set to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

let someone else do the try-catch-stuff and use [Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

One of the `closeQuietly()`-methods (e.g. [this one](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29)) should be just what you need:

> Equivalent to InputStream.close(), except any exceptions will be ignored. This
>   is typically used in finally blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7 it's suppose to be this

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(props)) {
    ...
}
```

before Java 7

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection();
try {
  ...
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you nullify and not closed,Make sure all methods always get a new open connection.**

The only thing you need to know is that any time you get a connection you *must* close it (hence the finally block) else you may leave that connection open in your application and eventually run out of available connections.